# Is there a Jest hook that can be used to exit testing if some pre-conditions are not met?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am developing a NodeJS server app and have the following query.

Is there a Jest hook that exists that can check for a condition(s) and will only starts testing if true? If the condition is not true then the test process does not start and a message is displayed on console.

If not, then guess I could use package.json pre-script that will trigger a shell script that performs conditional check(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Places that are common to a group of tests can be used.

For a specific test group it's `beforeAll`:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
  ...
  if !(condition)
    throw new Error('Condition not met');
});
```

For all test suites it's [setup file](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array):

```
module.exports = async () => {
  ...
  if !(condition)
    throw new Error('Condition not met');
};
```